# How to recycle an [x, y] vector while adding a 2 x z matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

How can I do this without the first `replicate` using recycling or matrix multiplication?

```
replicate(5, c(-74.04456199608506, 40.68923184725649)) + replicate(5, rnorm(2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use `+`, therefore using recycling:

```r
replicate(5, rnorm(2)) + c(-74.04456199608506, 40.68923184725649)
```

output

```r
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
[1,] -74.30676 -75.55923 -74.57547 -73.35665 -75.33159
[2,]  39.11709  39.08770  39.22748  42.78934  41.47697
```

Comment: I guess you can do without creating `x` as an intermediate variable,  `c(-74.04456199608506, 40.68923184725649) + replicate(5, rnorm(2))` should work as well.

Comment: Of course. Obviously I had a temporary knot in my brain^^

Answer (score 2):

You could use `sweep()`:

```
x <- replicate(5, rnorm(2))
sweep(x, 1, c(-74.04456199608506, 40.68923184725649), FUN = `+`)
```

Results check:

```
identical(replicate(5, c(-74.04456199608506, 40.68923184725649)) + x,
          sweep(x, 1, c(-74.04456199608506, 40.68923184725649), FUN = `+`))

[1] TRUE
```